# Creating Webuser control for Sidebar dashboard with modal popUp for each item

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, repeater, webusercontrol

Hi basically i want to create a Control that can add popup to menuItems which is declared in the markup of the page. I would like the syntax to be like below:

```
<uc1:Sidebar id="" runat="server" enablePopup="True">
<PopUpBindings>
<PopedControlId="" BackgroundClass="" TargetItemIndex=""/>
<PopedControlId="" BackgroundClass="" TargetItemIndex=""/>
..
</PopUpBindings>
</uc1:Sidebar>
```

I am able to create enablePopUp using Member Fields in the asmx Page. Like Below

```
private bool _enablePopup;
public Boolean EnablePopup
{
    get { return _enablePopup; }
    set { _enablePopup = value; }
}
```

but creating a bindings set as in markUp 1. Never done that before. Could someone give hints to this.
Question 2:
This usercontrol is being created because modalPopup could not be created along with Repeater's Databinding. I tried the below in repeaters ItemDatabound event but would throw exception **"Target control Id ={0}  could not be found"**

```
mpcpnlNewBp.TargetControlID = e.Item.ID;//open modalpopup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Collection properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178654.aspx) on your control - see [this example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9txe1d4x.aspx) from MSDN to get an idea.

If more designer support such as UI for editing properties is needed then you need to create Collection Editor - check [this related example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zky1t4k.aspx).

EDIT:
With templated controls such as repeater, target control needs to be found in the correct parent control context which Modal Popup cannot do. The solution is to use a dummy (hidden) control on the page/user control as a target control for the modal popup and then use extender's java-script API to hide/show popup as per needs (see [this article](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View38736C2B-BAD3-418A-A5B0-DAC4F1A5A83A.htm) for client side API).

Comment: superb answer although i don't know how i can use it in my problem. Also do you know any way i can use modalPopup along with repeater. The code behind section code 3 in my question throws a exception although the control Id exists in Page. I even Tried ClientId doesn't help

Comment: @Deeptechtons, my mistake - missed the second question completely! ModalPopup will be unable to find the control within repeater because the control has to be searched within specific repeater item. So alternative is to use a dummy target and user java-script API to show/hide the control - see my edited answer.